# C++ functions and MPI programing

Tags: mpi

From what I have learned in my supercomputing class I know that MPI is a communicating (and data passing) interface.

I'm confused on when you run a function in a C++ program and want each processor to perform a specific task.

For example, a prime number search (very popular for supercomputers). Say I have a range of values (531-564, some arbitrary range) and say I have 50 processes I could run a series of evaluations on for each number. If root (process 0) wants to examine 531 and knowing prime numbers I can use 8 processes (1-8) to evaluate the prime status. If the number is divisible by any number 2-9 with a remainder of 0, then it is not prime.

Is it possible that for MPI which passes data to each process to have these processes perform these actions?

The hardest part for me is understanding that if I perform an action in the original C++ program the processes taking place could be allocated on several different processes, then in MPI how can I structure this? Or is my understanding completely wrong? If so how am I supposed to truly go about this path of thinking in a correct manner?

The big idea is *passing data to a process* versus having a *function sent to a process*. I'm fairly certain I'm wrong but I'm trying to back track to fix my thinking.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking whether MPI is a Remote Procedure Call (RPC) framework, right? MPI is not exactly a RPC framework, although I think they support it (or its support is planned) in the latest standard. Before trying to solve your own problems using MPI, you should start off with the most basic examples in a guided tutorial (there are many around), such as the *hello, world* program. In any case, the usual way is to exchange the data through the network without having to deal with all the networking stuff (sockets,etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! First I do understand a simple Hello with MPI where I use rank and world size to say hello from those processes along with reporting their rank and the world size. In my prime example my question is that in a given program how is the executing working among the processes? Say I want to distribute division remainder work along 8 processes (%2~%9) to check if they are divisible by these numbers. How does this executing method work or is my understanding of MPI wrong in terms of how the scheduler distributes the functions amoung the processes.

Comment: A secondary question would be that when I do the Hello with MPI that I described earlier does each node execute the entirety of the program? So if I run over 5 nodes each process would be an execution of this program and not just bits scattered among the nodes?

Comment: MPI is an implementation of "manual" parallelism, so to say. It doesn't do any work distribution for you. It just carries data between independent entities, called ranks and most often implemented as separate processes, and provides some group operations for your convenience and performance. There is no built-in automatic work distribution like in OpenMP or in the PGAS languages. Calling functions in remote processes is not part of MPI, though it could be built on top of it.

Comment: @BrandonWilliams there are other examples, not only a *hello, world* program. A really popular example similar to yours is the PI number computation. You should check it out.

Comment: Thank you guys! and @JorgeBellón I looked at examples of that and ran a few thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each MPI process is running the same program, but that doesn't mean that they are doing the same thing.  Different processes can be running different branches of the code, depending on the id (or "rank") of the process, and in effect be completely independent.  Like any distributed computation, the actors do need to agree on how they will communicate.

The most basic strategy in MPI is scatter-gather, where the "master" process (usually the one with rank 0) will split an array of work equally amongst the peers (including the master process itself) by having them all call scatter, the peers will do the work, then all peers will call gather to send the results back to master.

In your prime algorithm example, build an array of integers, "scatter" it to all the peers, each peer will run through its array saving 1 if it is prime, 0 if it is not then "gather" the results to master.  [In this particular example, since the input data is completely predictable based on process rank, the scatter step is unnecessary but we will do it anyway.]

As pseudo-code:

```
main():
  int x[n], n = 100
  MPI_init()
  // prepare data on master
  if rank == 0:  
      for i in 1 ... n, x[i] = i

  // send data from x on root to local on each process in world
  MPI_scatter(x, n, int, local, n/k, int, root, world)  
  for i in 1 ... n/k
      result[i] = 1   // assume prime 
      if 2 divides local[i], result[i] = 0
      if 3 divides local[i], result[i] = 0
      if 5 divides local[i], result[i] = 0
      if 7 divides local[i], result[i] = 0

  // gather reults from local on each process in world to x on root
  MPI_gather(result, n/k, int, x, n, int, root, world)

  // print results
  if rank == 0:
      for i in 1 ... n, print i if x[i] == 1
  MPI_finalize()
```

There are lots of details to fill in such as proper declarations, and dealing with the fact that some ranks will have fewer elements than others, using
proper C syntax, etc., but getting them right doesn't help explain the overall picture.

More fine-grained synchronization and communication is possible using direct send/recv between processes.  Such programs are harder to write since the different processes may be in different states.  In particular, it is important that if process a is calling MPI_send to process b, then process b had better be calling MPI_recv from a.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've used your code and altered it probably 20 times to test and experiment and I have a better understanding. Thank you!